# Plotting graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Dataframe(153 rows X 2 columns) -
with Column 1 - Complaint Type (String)
and Column 2 - Count (int)

I need to plot this with y axis = count and x axis = complaint type(string)

I saw an answer that i can use xticks to use string as my x axis labels -

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
y = np.array([20,21,22,23])
my_xticks = ['John','Arnold','Mavis','Matt']
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

But how can i plot when i don't even have integer/float values as my variables.
I get Value Error: Cannot convert string to float.

Comment: Waht about `df.plot(x='col1', y='col2')` ?

Comment: How can i create a bar graph since it will be more informative?

Comment: I add it to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bar chart, you can call `df.plot.bar('Complaint Type', 'Count')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.plot.bar(x='col1', y='col2')
```

Solution for lines with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot(x='col1', y='col2')
```